# EF Core 2.1 - Query types support with models

Tags: ef-core-2.1

While I use DbQuery, should the columns in the select statement query match exactly same as the model/entity?

Below is the example:

```
IEnumerable<UserModel> test =  _context.FewUserColumns.FromSql(@"select id, 
                               last_name, from user where user_id = @userId", 
                               param).ToListAsync();
```

Below is the UserModel.

```
public class userModel
{
        public int id {get;set;}
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
}
```

I am not fetching first_name in the above select statement. due to this i see the below error.

*An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The required column 'first_name' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.*

Is that expected? Should we always fetch all the columns to map to all the properties in the model?

Comment: Well, it sounds logical to me - that's why they are called query types. Or better said, query **result** types.

Comment: Thank you Ivan. In that case, i end up creating another model that matches the select query or Is it OK to bring in 'first_name' column details also along and use the same model though I will not require 'first_name'?

Comment: Why not `SELECT NULL AS first_name`?

Comment: Thanks Bricelam. That should be fine. but, my example just shows one missing column. there could be scenarios where each of my select statements look different and i simply cant mark the missing columns with null values. upcoming releases should consider your suggestion instead we marking null for missing columns ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had posted a similar query on msdn and received a response from [Julie Lerman](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/c59d5f99-69b3-4438-88a9-c0ac356d1b53/data-points-ef-core-21-query-types?forum=msdnmagazine#5d60fbf8-3958-4dbe-b921-58635d0ce21c):

> Yes, unfortunately that is a constraint...EF Core expects all of those
>   properties to be available.